# Create and render multiple images on the fly in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am working on the following code. Why am I not able to render generated images to the page on the fly?

```
<?php
 for ($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++) {
   $im = imagecreatetruecolor(320, 80);
   $text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
   imagestring($im, 20, 20, 5,  "Test App", $text_color);

   $img = imagejpeg($im, 'Test.jpg');

   echo '<div class="map"><img src="'.$img.'" class="img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre"></div>';

  imagedestroy($im);
  }
?>
```

What I am getting in the output now is

[image]

while the `src` attributes of the images are `1` !

[image]

Comment: `$img` is set to true because `imagejpeg()` is returning a boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture the byte stream, then convert. You'll need to `base64_encode` the raw byte. Then use it in the image tag:

Basic idea:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    ob_start(); // begin capture
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor(320, 80);
    $text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    imagestring($im, 20, 20, 5,  "Test App " . ($i + 1), $text_color);

    $img = imagejpeg($im, null, 100);
    $raw = ob_get_clean(); // get

    echo '<div class="map"><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($raw).'" class="img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre"></div>';
}
```

Comment: This answer is complete for the question and should work for the person asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

An <img> tag expects you to supply a filename. Hence you need to save the files and then reference the saved name or your need to embed your image data using something like this:

[Embedding Base64 Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images)

Comment: You don't need to save any image file to reference it.

Answer (score 0):

`imagejpeg()` returns a boolean according to its docs here: [PHP imagejpeg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) -- Meaning whether it successfully created the image stream or not.

On the display page you can do something like this:

```
<div class="map">
    <img src="image.php" class="img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre">
</div>
```

Create a file called `image.php` and set this as source:

```
<?php
  $im = imagecreatetruecolor(320, 80);
  $text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
  imagestring($im, 20, 20, 5,  "Test App", $text_color);

  header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

  $img = imagejpeg($im);

  imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

This will actually treat `image.php` as an image file. You have to have headers set properly on the output, which your code example won't do. The browser needs to know how to handle data streams.

Comment: This is obviously an example of just one image, but you can take it and run with it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be better to have two separate PHP files:
One which creates the image on-the-fly and returns the data as a JPEG image (say image.php), and another one which renders the HTML code.
Then your HTML would contain something like:

```
<img src="image.php?param1=value1&moreParams">
```

The other option would be to keep using a single PHP file, and convert the binary JPEG image into a base64 string. This is because the "src" attribute either expects a "normal" URL, or base64-encoded image data. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21606233/4555850